# Problems using Mashape API in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, exception, mashape

I found some great code on the net for using the Mashape API to get a QR code. [Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Community/2012/12/02/mashape-api-how-to-consume-in-wp/).

Their code works great, but if I try and change it to use another Mashape, I get a

> "An exceptions occured during the operation, making the result
>   invalid"

error. And something about checking the inner exception.

Code below shows QR code from link and my goes at trying to use a Weather API and the Spotify API.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    client.Headers["X-Mashape-Authorization"] = "mashape-api-code-goes-here";

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    // For Spotify (this doesn't work)
    // postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "q", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtArtitst.Text));
    // var uri = new Uri("https://mager-spotify-web.p.mashape.com/search/1/artist.json?", UriKind.Absolute);

    // For Weather info (this doesn't work)
    postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "_method", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("getForecasts"));
    postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "location", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("brisbane"));
    var uri = new Uri("https://george-vustrey-weather.p.mashape.com/api.php?", UriKind.Absolute);

    // For QR Code (this works)
    //postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "content", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TestQRCode"));
    //postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "quality", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("L"));
    //postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "type", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("text"));
    //postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "size", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("5"));
    //var uri = new Uri("https://mutationevent-qr-code-generator.p.mashape.com/generate.php?", UriKind.Absolute);

    client.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());
    txtResult.Text = postData.ToString();

    progress1.IsIndeterminate = true;
    button1.IsEnabled = false;
}


void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progress1.IsIndeterminate = false;

    var client = sender as WebClient;
    client.UploadStringCompleted -= client_UploadStringCompleted;
    string response = string.Empty;
    if (!e.Cancelled)
    {
        try
        {
            response = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(e.Result);  // seems to error out here - result invalid
            txtResult.Text = response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtResult.Text = "ERROR : " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    button1.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

The inner exception says :

**InnerException**

```
    {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)}   System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: added inner exception

Comment: This looks suspicious:
client.Headers["X-Mashape-Authorization"] = "mashape-api-code-goes-here";

Comment: naturally, i have replaced the API key i am using with the text "mashape-api-code-goes-here" so that nobody else can use it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project so that investigation could be faster?

Comment: with GET method it gives an inner exception - "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."
After changing the method type to "POST" it throws inner exception - "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a GET instead of a POST?

Also, can you try application/json instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded

A working example on Windows 8 here - https://github.com/ismaelc/Mashape_Windows8_Sample/blob/master/App5/App5/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: I still got a "TargetInvocationException" error with both of those changes. I'll take a look at your example and recode mine to match and see how i go.

Comment: Here's another repo - https://github.com/ismaelc/MashapeFBSentimentExample You can ignore the consumerkey and consumersecret keys they don't apply anymore